# Gas estimation reverts

Tags: gas, javascript, kovan, function

I am quite new to blockchain programming and am trying to estimate the gas cost of calling a function from a smart contract.

I am using Web3 js and the Kovan network through an Infura node.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code used to estimate the function gas cost:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
const { Contract } = require("web3-eth-contract");

// Web3 setup
const web3 = new Web3("https://kovan.infura.io/v3/PROJECTID")
var abi = the abi code from etherscan
var LSPContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x2aA95512fC0898C34e60A5c3708f36e9fE990C02');

async function getGas() {
  let gasAmount = await LSPContract.methods.create(1000).estimateGas();
  return gasAmount;
}

getGas()
  .then(function(gasAmount){
    console.log("Using the create costed: " + gasAmount + " wei")
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

This is the full trace of the error:

```
 Error: Returned error: The execution failed due to an exception.
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/folder/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /Users/folder/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/folder/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/folder/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/folder/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/folder/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/folder/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1333:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  data: 'Reverted'
}
```

**UPDATE**

Functions which do not change the EVM state work fine. I also tried to send signed transactions but no luck, they reverted as well.

Comment: Did you try creating fewer tokens? start with 1, then increasing it. Also you can override the default gas limit with `.estimateGas({ gas: "50000000" });`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with only one token and a higher gas limit but I am still getting the same error. I am currently recreating the same code in Python.

Comment: Without the source code it is impossible to narrow down the error.

Comment: It worked with functions which do not change the state of the EVM. Guessing it can not estimate the costs of transactions using the send() option.

Comment: Try explicitly setting "from" at `send()` with a valid address.